# Site structure for multiple page Facebook Canvas app

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, webforms, facebook-canvas

This may seem like an obvious problem, but I have looked on the facebook developers site regarding canvas apps, and on the [facebook csharp sdk](http://csharpsdk.org/) and have not found an answer to my questions.

I'm using the facebook-c#-sdk v5.4x or something abouts, .net 3.5 using webforms.

The canvas app for desktop will have multiple entry points.

`https://apps.facebook.com/my_canvas_app/Default.aspx`
`https://apps.facebook.com/my_canvas_app/Register.aspx?EventID=12345`
`https://apps.facebook.com/my_canvas_app/SomeOtherPage.aspx`

My first question is that from the first request from facebook, I receive the `signed_request` (which *facebook-c#-sdk* takes care of), I have the oauth token, which is valid for approximately 2 hours.  What is the correct way to re-new this oauth token, and ensure it's valid before trying to make an oauth request (query the graph, etc.)?

Right now all my links (say from Default.aspx) look like `<a href="https://apps.facebook.com/my_canvas_app/SomeOtherPage.aspx" target="_top">Go to Some Other Page</a>`, which ends up doing a round trip to facebook, getting a new `signed_request`, and thus a renewed oauth token.

Secondly, When doing a regular form postback though asp.net to my own site, I ensure the `signed_request` is on the form with a simple `<input type="hidden" name="signed_request" value="<%=Request.Form["signed_request"]%>" />`, which seems to work fine for the the application.  If I omit this then the postback does not have the oauth information, resulting in things failing.  Is this the correct way to perform a postback in a canvas app?  From what I can see from viewing the source of the csharp-sdk that nothing is stored in the session to preserve the oauth token between requests, so the hidden input, and target="_top" links are required for multiple pages / postbacks, am I correct in this deduction?

Thirdly, when developing the mobile canvas app (without the iframe), do all the links on my page still have to go to `https://apps.facebook.com/my_canvas_app/MobilePage.aspx`, if my first assumption is correct that is.

If anyone could shed some light on these subjects I would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am doing is using the `signed_request` on a per-page basis.  All links in the desktop environment go to `http://apps.facebook.com/myappnamespace/MyPageName.aspx` with a `target="_top"`, this way every page change gets an updated oauth token.  Mobile operates differently as `signed_request` is not available for the mobile experience.  The solution for this is to use server side authentication instead.  I am not using `http://apps.facebook.com/myappnamespace` for the mobile environment as it's not within an iframe.  Mobile operates like any other regular website.

Answer (score 2):

> Right now all my links (say from Default.aspx) look like Go to Some Other Page, which ends up doing a round trip to facebook, getting a new signed_request, and thus a renewed oauth token.

I'd suggest also embedding the JavaScript SDK into your pages - a call to FB.getLoginStatus then should also get you a valid access token every time.
The other thing you could do, is exchange that short-time access token you get at user login for a long-time one, see https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

If you *don't* save your access token into some kind of session, then I guess you'll have to transfer it from page to page via postback, yes.

(And maybe you should take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/ as well.)

Comment: I am looking to do all the oauth without javascript if it all possible.  If javascript is required, then why have a `signed_request` at all?  My understanding was that `signed_request` is an alternative to using the javascript lib.

Comment: If you're doing server-side auth, then the access token should be valid for around 60 days, not just two hours (see: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)